# HDRP project error - unity

Tags: unity

i just created a new HDRP project and my scene is blank. Pls Help!!!

Unity view:
[image]

Error: RenderTexture.Create failed: format unsupported for random writes - RGBA16 SFloat

Comment: This looks like a bug to report to the Unity developers. Can you tell us anything about the system you're running this on? (OS, graphics card, driver version...)

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: after sometime i got to know that it isnt showing because of my opengl version

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below, so it can help future users who experience this error.